# chartjs-chart-boxplot how don't consider outlier has it

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I try to do a boxplot chart but my database is huge and I analyzed it for the first time. I copy my data in my js script so that it directly displays the boxplot but the max is considered an outlier (which is not in my database).
And is it possible to change the range outlier or something like that?

My data in chart.js:

```
data: [
                    [1,20,28,42,87],
                    [1,21,34,50,98],
                    [1,21,45,61,98],
                    [2,37,58,70,97],
                ],
```

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?